# typescript Reactjs how to find Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Char' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I get the error in the title on `npm run start` (as I am loading the application). The following is the trace I get from the console in Dev Tools:

```
BackgroundDTO.ts:162 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Char' before initialization
    at Module.Char (BackgroundDTO.ts:162:1)
    at Module.Char (Weapon.ts:26:1)
    at registerExportsForReactRefresh (RefreshUtils.js:173:1)
    at Object.executeRuntime (RefreshUtils.js:205:1)
    at $ReactRefreshModuleRuntime$ (index.ts:26:1)
    at ./src/features/character/models/specs/index.ts (index.ts:26:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/features/character/models/specs/Char.ts (BackgroundDTO.ts:162:1)
Char @ BackgroundDTO.ts:162
Char @ Weapon.ts:26
registerExportsForReactRefresh @ RefreshUtils.js:173
executeRuntime @ RefreshUtils.js:205
$ReactRefreshModuleRuntime$ @ index.ts:26
./src/features/character/models/specs/index.ts @ index.ts:26
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/features/character/models/specs/Char.ts @ BackgroundDTO.ts:162
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/features/character/characterSlice.ts @ index.ts:8
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/app/store.ts @ hooks.ts:6
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/index.tsx @ StrikerPlaceholder.tsx:4
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
```

Naturally, I went to BackgroundDTO.ts and Weapon.ts to see if I am referring to Char before I have initialised it or declared it, and neither of these files even reference Char. Also, neither of these files reference each other.

On the possibility that there's circular reference somewhere I ran `npm -g install madge` and ran its circular reference detection on the main index.ts and App.ts files, and it found none. I also ran it on the index.ts file in the ./specs directory, just in case madge couldn't descend, but, similarly, nothing found.

I have something like 80 files overall that could be making a reference to Char before initialisation (which is why I'm not supplying a jsfiddle or similar), but without any clue as to where, its close to impossible to find it. I have been trying, but its been a couple of days now.

Does anyone know how to find the ReferenceError? Or is this something that comes up because of cached js lib builds or something?

The repo is here: https://gitlab.com/mikeycoxon/zgf-dablogga

The issue is under the react application, which is under the "frontend" directory.

Comment: Can you link to the repo?

Comment: good idea, just edited the question, adding the repo info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue!! well, sort of.

In the file: `src/features/character/characterSlice.ts`

I changed the import for Char from:

`import { Char } from "./models/specs/Char.ts"`

to:

`import { Char } from "./models/specs"`

and the whole project did not blow up anymore.

I have no idea why that works (or the first form failed), but it seems making specific references to files with exports is dangerous, very dangerous.

I leave it to better minds than mine to explain why.